# Java "User" class naming best practice?

Tags: java, naming

I'm about to create a User class for my project.  Any opinions as to whether it is bad practice to create such a commonly-named class?  I could complement it with a prefix specific to my project.

Comment: is that project meant to be used as a library by other projects (and User going to be a public class)?

Comment: No.  Proprietary web project.  I'm actually pretty comfortable with keeping User as User, but we also have another domain concept of a Session.  Haven't gotten to it yet but naming on that one is already giving me heartburn.

Answer (score 3):

This is what [packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package) are for.

Comment: Well you might end up importing two packages having "User" class. That would probably cause some headaches.

Comment: @Ravi, but if that were to be an issue, then you could refer to the classes by their fully qualified names.

Comment: @Michael: That's true, but I feel that it hurts the readability of the code.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to definitely prefix an application specific term to your User class. "User" is way too common and vague. You might easily end up using API which has "User" class or Interface. Though latest IDEs make it relatively easy to refactor your code, it would be cleaner and easier if you have a app specific "User" class.

Comment: I agree with you. It starts becoming a mess when you have multiple classes with same name.

Answer (score 1):

Using common names is not a bad practice, until and unless you describe the name as that to the functionality of the class. keep in mind to create proper packages that can define your class more specifically.

Answer (score 1):

I always try to use common names like User for clarity. Just be sure the names are drawn from the problem domain and existing project vocabulary. Be alert for ambiguities, and if one arise, change the class name.  Modern IDEs with automated refactoring support make that easy.

Comment: Yes. Having correct class name in appropriate package will be the right thing. IDEs like IntelliJ very good support for searching and importing class names - it can be even automatic.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Java `package`s to avoid name clashes. There is nothing wrong with using a common name, just be sure to put it in its own package. For example, you could have the following structure:

```
com/
  yourwebsite/
      yourproject/
            userdata/
                 User.java
```

You then begin the file "User.java" with:

```
package com.yourwebsite.yourproject.userdata;
```

When you import it, you would use:

```
import com.yourwebsite.yourproject.userdata.User;
```

Comment: I would still suggest that people do not name their classes "String" or "List" or "Collection" or "Exception" or "Connection" or "Session". I am fine with "User", if only because it is not commonly used elsewhere (in my current workspace, which has many libraries, there is only one in "com.sun.tools.internals..." and one in "org.hsqldb", none of which you are likely to use).

Comment: @Thilo, yeah, I certainly would not use names that are already in use in any of the "java.*" or "javax.*" packages, but there is no User class in the Java API as of this writing.

Answer (score 0):

This name is unlikely to be used by any public API, so it's ok for an app to use it.